# Uploading Arduino firmware automatically

Tags: powershell, arduino

I am on Windows 8.1. I have an Arduino Uno kit, that I program with the help of Arduino IDE. The IDE allows me to edit my files, compile them and burn them into the Arduino memory. However, I have several different Arduino files, all for different purposes. And for what I am trying to achieve, I am not allowed to manually invoke the IDE, select a file and upload it to Arduino. Instead, I need to automate the process of choosing the correct file to upload to Arduino, and upload it automatically.

So, my question is, for a given Arduino program file, how does one upload it to Arduino programmatically, eg. through a powershell script. i.e not upload it manually by clicking the upload button in Arduino IDE.

Comment: I'm not sure about your command line/powershell scripting background, but the latest Arduino software supports command line now: http://lifehacker.com/arduino-ide-now-supports-building-software-in-the-comma-1740786363

Answer (score 0):

Move to the arduino folder from cmd using 
`cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino"` or the path to your installation dir.
Please note that you already need to install the full arduino IDE not the WEB.

then
 `arduino.exe --upload /path/to/sketch/sketch.ino`

Obtained from 
https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=550577.0

Check out this link with the full tutorial for linux also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qAM2S27FWAI

Explaining it all along it's gonna be a bit long, and it is not the purpose of the forum.

Main rules for forums:
1: Google before asking: http://bfy.tw/NH6M. It is rude to ask for something already solved or widely explained and people usually gets angry.
2: Search for the proper forum https://forum.arduino.cc/
3: Read the forum and working rules

Then: 
Ask

If this answer is useful vote and chose the most useful answer. 
That's how this community works.

Comment: Necroposting, but: The question was posted 2015. You answer this in 2019, cite a source dated 2018, and blame the OP for not doing research?